# Python Iteration of Two Pandas Dataframes, Duplicate Error

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I am trying to iterate over two pandas dataframes (A & B) using nested for loops. An if statement is inserted after the second for loop. The goal is to match an unique_id column from dataframes A and B and then append another column value to an empty list.

Instead of receiving 1 name per unique id, I receive 6. It seems like the loop does not iterate once there is a match.

Assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
empty_list = []

for i, r in dfA.iterrows():
  for j, ro in dfB.iterrows():
     if (r['unique_id'] == ro['unique_id]):
         empty_list.append(ro['name'])
         print(r['unique_id'], ro['unique_id], ro['name'])
     else: 
         pass
```

```
unique_id Name
1.    John
1.    John
1.    John
1.    John
1.    John


Desired Output: 
1.    John
2.    Bob
3.    Ryan
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal sample of your data (as text) and the expected output so that the problem can be reproduced

Comment: It is difficult to comment without data, but does your DataFrame `dfB` contain repeated values of `unique_id`?

Comment: @Mortz Yes I think that is the problem. There were repeated id's in data frames A and B. That is why each name was repeated 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some data for others to help you faster.
Here is something to start with.

Your code works fine (except there were two typos; apos missing).

Also, there are better ways to "join" the two dataframes.

One reason you might be seeing 6 could be duplicates in unique_id column in original data.

```
import pandas as pd, io

raw1 = '''unique_id,name
1,A
2,B
3,C
'''
raw2 = '''unique_id,name
3,C
4,D
5,E
'''

dfA = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw1))
dfB = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw2))

empty_list = []

for i, r in dfA.iterrows():
  for j, ro in dfB.iterrows():
     if (r['unique_id'] == ro['unique_id']):
         empty_list.append(ro['name'])
         print(r['unique_id'], ro['unique_id'], ro['name'])
     else: 
         pass
```

Output:

```
3 3 C
```